# Spring @Value assigning null to variable. @PropertySource

Tags: spring

I am trying to use the @Value annotation on a variable to assign a value, but the value getting assigned is null.  What am I doing wrong?  I am using the java spring configuration using @Configuration.  I am also using @PropertySource to point to a properties file.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Value("${app_prop_1}") Integer aValue;

    @Bean
    public Integer getInteger() {
        return new Integer(aValue);  // throws NullPointerException
    }
}
```

The application.properties files is in the maven resources folder of project.  It has following content:

```
app_prop_1=2000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @Value annotation always evaluating as null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130486/spring-value-annotation-always-evaluating-as-null)

Comment: Hint: according to the comments at https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8539 it is not recommended to use `@Value` in `@Configuration` instead one should use `@Inject Environment env;` and then `env.getProperty("app_prop_")`

Answer (score 3):

When you add `@Value` annotation, there is a need to add

```
//To resolve ${} in @Value
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

This will resolve the `${}` expression.

[Source](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-propertysources-example/)

Comment: More details at: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html section "Using the @Value annotation"