# NullPointerException when using bean in class method

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a Spring-boot app. 
I want to use variable from application.properties in class method but I have nullPointerException.

Here's a simple example that doesn't work.

application.properties:

```
#data paths
file.path=C:\\Users\\apodar\\autoTest
```

Config.java

```
package com.eserv.autotest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Config {

@Value("${file.path}")
String filePath;

    public String getFilePath() { return filePath; }
    public String getScreenshotsPath() {
        return getFilePath() + "/screenshots";
       }

}
```

AutotestApplication.java

```
package com.eserv.autotest;

import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackageClasses = {
            AutotestApplication.class,
       }
)
public class AutotestApplication implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AutotestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

         System.out.println("DATASOURCE = " + dataSource);

    }
 }
```

SeleniumTestExecutionListener:

```
    public class SeleniumTestExecutionListener extends AbstractTestExecutionListener {

    @Inject Config config;

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @Override
    public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        if (testContext.getTestException() == null) {
            return;
        }
        File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        String testName = toLowerUnderscore(testContext.getTestClass().getSimpleName());
        String methodName = toLowerUnderscore(testContext.getTestMethod().getName());

        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File( config.getScreenshotsPath() + testName + "_" + methodName + "_" + screenshot.getName()));
    }

}
```

Why does `config.getScreenshotsPath()` method doesn't return path. `config` is null.

Comment: can you provide your class annotated with @SpringBootApplication?

Comment: Autowiring doesn't work in a `TestExecutionListener`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring @Value annotation always evaluating as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130486/spring-value-annotation-always-evaluating-as-null)

Comment: @MironBalcerzak I have edit post with SpringBootApplication class.

Comment: SeleniumTestExecutionListener  is not @Component? Then Spring doesn't care about its autowiring. Then autowired fields like config are not properly initialized.

Comment: @M.Deinum: Could you please tell me how can a get the value from `application.properties` in `SeleniumTestExecutionListener`?

Comment: Regardless the `TestExecutionListener` instances aren't under spring control (not the application context) but the test execution framework. You cannot auto wire into a `TestExecutionListener` for exactly that reason. You. need to retrieve the `ApplicationContext` from the `TestContext` and retrieve the `Config` object from that.

Comment: @AlexanderAnikin: Even I annotate with @Component `SeleniumTestExecutionListener `, `config` is still null.

Comment: @M.Deinum: your answer seems to be rightful but, because I'm beginner I don't understand so well. If is ok (some people say that I did not make any research effort ), could you please help me with references how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: I basically explained that word for word... `testContext.getApplicationContex().getBean(Config.class)` if you want the code.

Comment: @M.Deinum: It works in this way, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autowiring in a `TestExecutionListener` will not work. The creation and lifecycle of the `TestExecutionListener` instances is managed by the Test Context framework of Spring and that isn't part of the `ApplicationContext` but external. Hence auto wiring will not work.

If you want to use beans in your `TestExecutionListener` instead retrieve the `ApplicationContext` from the `TestContext`.

```
@Override
public void afterTestMethod(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
    if (testContext.getTestException() == null) {
        return;
    }

    final Config config = testContext.getApplicationContext().getBean(Config.class);
    File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) webDriver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String testName = toLowerUnderscore(testContext.getTestClass().getSimpleName());
    String methodName = toLowerUnderscore(testContext.getTestMethod().getName());

    FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File( config.getScreenshotsPath() + testName + "_" + methodName + "_" + screenshot.getName()));
}
```