# SpringBoot with @Value property in Filter is null

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using SpringBoot's @Value annotation to populate an object property from the default application.properties file, but seeing some strange behaviour in a Filter override.

There are two breakpoints in my debugger:

```
@Component
  public class BasicFilter implements Filter {

  @Value("${aad.client_id}")
  private String clientId;

  @Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean registerFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(new BasicFilter()); // <-- 1.
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/secure/*");
    return registration;
  }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) { // <- 2.
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        ...
```

At 1.: `this.client_id` is set to 'foo' (from application.properties
A2 2.: `this.client_id` is null

Any explanation for the different/missing values?

Comment: show us your properties file entry where it is declared

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're injecting a `new BasicFilter()` into the `FilterRegistrationBean`. In this case, you're creating a new object, but it won't be a Spring managed bean, so its `clientId` will be empty. So basically you have 2 instances now:

1. One created by Spring due to the `@Component` annotation
2. One injected into the `FilterRegistrationBean` using the `new` keyword (not managed by Spring)

You should likely move the `registerFilter()` method to a separate configuration class (annotated with `@Configuration)` and autowire/inject the `BasicFilter` bean into that method, eg:

```
@Configuration
public class FilterConfig {
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean registerFilter(BasicFilter filter) { // Inject it
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter); // Use it
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/secure/*");
        return registration;
   }
}
```

Altenatively, if you want to keep the `@Bean` method in the filter itself, you should replace it by `this`, since the current object is managed by Spring, while the new instance won't be:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean registerFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    registration.setFilter(this);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/secure/*");
    return registration;
}
```

Related: [Spring @Value annotation always evaluating as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130486/spring-value-annotation-always-evaluating-as-null)