# How does spring boot @Value("${somevalue}") annotation work?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have some `@Value` annotation in spring-boot project. To Simplify, I have few classes: a restcontroller, service (annotated with @Service) and a pojo.
In each of these classes, I declared a variable as below:

```
@Value("${somevalue}")
private String somevalueVariable
```

1. In the controller class, the value is getting populated as defined in the application.properties. So no problem here.
2. In the service class, the value is showing up as null. **This is my issue, how should i fix it to get the value from the application.properties**

In the pojo, the value is showing up as null, I am thinking this is expected behaviour as spring does not manage this class.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18403937/7015400

Answer (score 1):

It uses Spring Expression Language (SpEL):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.RELEASE/reference/html/spel.html

Also there is 2 @Value : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value and lombok.Value;
Make sure you are using the right one.

To get value from property try this:

```
@Value("${systemValue}")
private String systemValue;
```

For more information I find this useful:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation

Comment: i am using the right annotation - `import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;`

Comment: then how is it working in the restcontroller class but not in the @Service class

Comment: Weird how its working in controller and not service ... try this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation#using-value-with-constructor-injection maybe

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;


@Value("#{${somevalue}}")
private String somevalueVariable
```

Answer (score 1):

`ideally service class should have @Service anotation over it, either you missed that or this class is not scanned by spring context, so please add ComponentScan anotation for service class package over main class to scan classes uner this package -`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.in28minutes.springboot"})
public class Application
```